# rotating a 3D point around the y axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

I have been provided with a rotation matrix to use:

[image: matrix]

and have entered the matrix into my function as

```
theta = radians(theta);
Ry(theta) = [cos(theta) 0 sin(theta); 0 1 0; -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
newpose = pos*Ry(theta);
```

yet whenever the function reaches this stage it returns the error

> ??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or
>   logicals.

any help much appreciated

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `Ry(theta)`.  Call it something like `Ry_theta` if you want it to be a variable, or put it in an actual function.  This should work:

```
theta = radians(theta);
Ry_theta = [cos(theta) 0 sin(theta); 0 1 0; -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
newpose = pos*Ry_theta;
```

Or - if you want a more reusable solution:

```
% in your existing file:
theta = radians(theta);
newpose = pos*rotationAboutYAxis(theta);;

% in a file called rotationAboutYAxis.m:
function Ry = rotationAboutYAxis(theta)
Ry = [cos(theta) 0 sin(theta); 0 1 0; -sin(theta) 0 cos(theta)];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ry(theta)
```

theta is most likely not a real positive integer or a logical.